# Using editor tokenColorCustomizations in VS Code user settings, how do I taget the "constant.function" scope seperately from errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, scope, settings

I am programming in python and trying to make errors realy stand out by turning them red. The best I have been able to find for the "error" scope is:

"scope": ["source.python"],

I can set normal functions blue with:

```
            "scope": [
                "entity.name.function",
                "entity.name.method",
                "punctuation.definition.method-call",
                "entity.name.type.method",
                "variable.other.member.function",
                "variable.other.member.method",
                "constant.function"
            ],
```

My own objects show up as constants,thier methods show as "constant.function". The function portion is apparently being handled in the same scope as my errors.